# How many arguments are required for PostGIS POLYGON()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

Postgres is throwing an error when I try to provide this as the value of a POLYGON column:

`POLYGON ((-10.5 10.5, 10.5 10.5, 10.5 -10.5, -10.5 -10.5))`

If I change it to this, then it works:

`POLYGON ((-10.5 10.5, 10.5 10.5, 10.5 -10.5, -10.5 -10.5, -10.5 10.5)`

but I don't understand why and I haven't been able to figure it out by reading about PostGIS POLYGON(). It is possible that I'm running PostGIS 2.5 while the code (which someone else wrote) assumes PostGIS 2.0, but I don't know that yet, and can't confirm it for other reasons.

Was there a change between PostGIS 2.0 and PostGIS 2.5 to how many arguments POLYGON() requires? Is there something else that I'm missing, as I don't know anything about PostGIS and this is outside the scope of what I'm actually responsible for working on.

Comment: it needs at least 4 coordinate pairs for a (valid as per OGC definition) triangular polygon: 3 corners described by a closed outer ring (LineString), meaning the end point equals the start point. what you seem to be doing is passing in a WKT defined string representation of a polygon, which, technically, is only one parameter. there is, however, no `POLYGON()` function in PostGIS; all (most) functions of the extension are prefixed by `ST_` (Spatial Type)

Answer (score 0):

Polygon is a closed linestring **with the same start and end point**

```
 POLYGON ((-10.5 10.5, 10.5 10.5, 10.5 -10.5, -10.5 -10.5))
 -- different start/end point, error!

 POLYGON ((-10.5 10.5, 10.5 10.5, 10.5 -10.5, -10.5 -10.5, -10.5 10.5))
 -- correct
```